# How many micro workouts are enough?

Tags: workout-routines, calisthenics

For someone who trains 3 times a week, performing only body weight exercises, how many micro workouts are enough?

What are the rules for micro workouts in terms of number of exercises, rest between the workouts, and training to failure?

My micro workouts will comprise two exercises. I intend to perform them 5 times a week (each micro workout will have different exercises) in the mornings. My aim is to do body weight exercises to improve my strength and conditioning.

Comment: You're going to need to define "micro workout" if you want anyone to be able to answer this. That isn't a term with any broadly accepted definition.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: It is still not at all clear what you are attempting to describe with the phrase "micro workout".

Comment: You also need to define enough "for what".  To maintain your current strength? Then whatever you're doing is fine.  If you've plateaued then you need to either do more or make them harder.